# MVC Project often recompiles after JS changes, don't know why, results in problems

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, compilation

I have a medium-sized ASP.NET MVC project with a lot of Javascript (Single-Page-App). Very often (dozens of times a day), when I edit the Javascript files and refresh it, I see in VS' output that it goes through the whole Application_Start process (as in (re-)starting the app).

This results in unwanted delays during development and after 2-4 such restarts, I get an InvalidOperationException "Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.". Since I do run it in the emulator, it seems to be that after a few app-restarts, it loses its connection to the emulator. Apart from that, I even got (although very rare) OutOfMemoryExceptions, which I can't find out where they are coming from, because nothing in the web app should allocate much memory and my workstation does have quite a lot (32 GiB).

It can't be related to an idle timeout for the IIS (Express) worker process, since the JS changes often only took seconds. I tried to reproduce it by adding spaces to the JS file and saving it, repeating that a few times and then trying to refresh. Weirdly, I was unable to reproduce it this way.

I am out of ideas, help would really be appreciated :)

[Edit]
Not an answer yet, but a possibility. It seems like Web Essentials is compiling my LESS files each time I save them (even after I specifically deactivated that because ASP.NET Bundling and Minification already handles that), which result in quite a few additional writes because I have the habit of saving VERY often. Already contacted the developer, maybe it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually due to IIS behaviour. IIS recycles any app if there is any change in the files in its file structure.

I had a similar experience and detailed my understanding here: http://www.geekays.net/post/2008/10/14/ASPNET-webdomain-recycle-on-subfolder-changes.aspx

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be helping .. The registry key had no effect and the other points should not apply to my scenario, as - besides VS itself - I don't have writes inside my web app directory. Well I'll search further, maybe there is some plugin etc. that does additional writes. Otherwise, the registry key should allow that.. very weird

Comment: I too found that the registry key was not helping. So we stopped deleting files. For you too, any change to the js files might be causing the recycle.

Comment: @Pharao2k: Look for the application pool. It may be safe to run your app in a separate application pool in IIS.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, but IIS Express does not support multiple application pools (as far as I know)

Comment: @Pharao2k: Right. So just see if you are changing any file. You are saying, you edit the JS file. So any change to ANY file withing the app is bound to recycle the app.